# Does Early Modern English Have Ablative Case?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, early-modern-english

I was thinking the other day, and a phrase popped into my mind that sounds as if I have heard it before, and I quickly realized it is not grammatically correct {on the surface.} It is:

"Get thee mee hence."

If this is a real phrase, {which it be,} is it an Ablative case-form?

Grammatically correct, that should be "Gettest thou, mee, hence," unless of course one were to use the verb "get" in a manner similar to "push," I would think.

---

If it is not ablative, and purely a scrambled brain-child, then I shall probably use it in poetry as an ablative case.

---

UPDATE: I know where I heard this from, [Matthew 4:10, in the Authorized Translation Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+4%3A10&version=AKJV), but my question stands.

> Then saith Jesus unto him, **Get thee hence**, Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve.

Which is closely related to [Matthew 16:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+16%3A23&version=AKJV):

> But he turned, and said unto Peter, **Get thee behind me**, Satan: thou art an offence unto me: for thou savourest not the things that be of God, but those that be of men.

Comment: Early Modern English did not decline nouns for case except the possessive.  EME declined pronouns in the nominative, oblique, genitive, and possessive. *Thee* and *me* are oblique, which serves for the objective (direct objects) and the dative (indirect objects). No ablative.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to comprehend that. I honestly don't understand that, because the person should be "getting hence," so it would make sense to me that it is nominative, but I thank you. I think I understand.

Comment: If this is Matthew 4:10, the meaning of your sentence is [Satan], *get yourself away from me here*. In Latin, the ablative case appears with certain prepositions, like *ab* or *ex* which would translate "away from", but no such case exists in English. But the koine just uses the imperative *Ὕπαγε* (go away).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I figured -- it was imperative. I have meditated on Oblique case, and I understand it now. You have been much a great help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a mistaken recollection of the text in question.

Comment: There were four deictic pronoun-like roots used in EME: _h-_, _th-_, _y-_, and _wh-_. Of these, three were used as the basis for adverb-like derivations with ablative meaning, ending in /ns/: _hence_, _thence_, and _whence_; ones with allative/illative meaning ending in /ðər/: _hither_, _thither_, _whither_; and ones with adessive/inessive meaning ending in /r/: _here_, _there_, _where_. The last root is etymologically unrelated and is found only in _yon((d)er)_, with allative/illative and adessive/inessive meanings. So there are ablative-like formations—but no ablative **case**.

Comment: "If this is a real phrase, {which it be,} is it an Ablative case-form?" : what 'it' are you talking about, 'thee' or 'mee'?